# Silverlight & CRM - How to bind a datagrid checkbox column to a two-state entity

Tags: silverlight, xaml, dynamics-crm

I have a Datagrid very similar to one provided in the SDK:

[image]

As you can see there are 2 checkbox columns, what I would like to do is bind a two-state field to these checkboxes (which are read-only, so checked if true).  Can anyone explain how to do this?

Or suggest a better approach to what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks,

Jack

EDIT; Failing this, just displaying the values (True/False) in the checkbox columns instead would suffice if thats possible?  There appears to be issues using a DataGrid and Multibinding..

Comment: Are you just wanting to set another object to readonly if one of the checkboxes is checked?

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes that was the next step after I had done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, its quite simple really, all you need to do is set the IsThreeState property of the datagridcheckbox column to true like so:

```
<sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn  x:Name="MyCheckBoxColumn" IsThreeState="True"  Header="Is On-Target?" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Path=my_IsOnTarget}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

The reason for this is because a '2-state' entity in CRM actually has three states (a nullable bool) which are true, false and null.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Multibinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286171/MultiBinding-in-Silverlight-5) can help to solve your problem.